# php fsockopen() fail issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, fsockopen

I'm trying to use xml rpc in remote server.

using codeigniter xml-rpc class.

the xml rpc server didn't send any data. so i tracked the library

and reached to here

```
- parameters


THIS->SERVER : 10.222.223.53
THIS->PORT : 80
THIS->errno : 
THIS->errstr : 
THIS->timeout : 5
```

these are the parameters and in here,

```
$fp = @fsockopen($this->server, $this->port,$this->errno, $this->errstring, 
 $this->timeout);
```

it returns FALSE, which means connection fail.

what should be the reason of this?

i checked 80 port is open with

this command

netstat -lntp

tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      6712/httpd

Comment: If you remove the `@` before `fsockopen` you will get more info on the error.

Comment: how can i check the err info after deleting it??

Comment: It will most probably be printed in your script's output. Also there is a better way - print $this->errno and $this->errstr after the call of the function.

Comment: Looks like I didn't explain what I mean - by removeing the `@` any warnings/errors by the function will be printed.

Comment: ok so i got this! THIS->errno : 110
THIS->errstr : Connection timed out. what will be the next step...

Comment: This is not a problem with your code - this error means that the connection to host `10.222.223.53` cannot be established in reasonable time. `netstat` will show that a service listens on a port but cannot show if connection can be made. You can test with `telnet 10.222.223.53 80`

Comment: Thanks man. the problem was the server's firewall gotcha!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments the problem is not in the code but in lack of connectivity. A firewall in the particular case.

To more easily debug the issue there are two approaches:

- remove the `@` that is suppressing warning/error output from the `fsockopen`
- inspect the values of `$this->errno` and `$this->errstr` after the call failed